# USB device Instace path usi WMI query c#

Tags: c#, usb, wmi

I am trying to find USB device instace path using following code and always getting an error regarding wrong query. Can anyone help me?

```
string strDeviceName = "USB\\VID_";
string Win32_PnPEntity = "Select * From Win32_PnPEntity Where DeviceID like '%" + strDeviceName + "%'" ;
ManagementObjectSearcher mySearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Win32_PnPEntity);
foreach (ManagementObject mobj in mySearcher.Get())
{
    string strDeviceID = mobj["DeviceID"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: string strDeviceName = "USB\\VID_";
            string Win32_PnPEntity = "Select * From Win32_PnPEntity Where DeviceID like '%" + strDeviceName + "%'" ;
            ManagementObjectSearcher mySearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Win32_PnPEntity);
            foreach (ManagementObject mobj in mySearcher.Get())
            {


                string strDeviceID = mobj["DeviceID"].ToString();

Comment: You can edit your own questions

Answer (score 0):

`string strDeviceName = "USB\\\\VID_";` or `string strDeviceName = @"USB\\VID_";`

This will work. You were missing one "\".